# Foul smell coming from around bathtub tap, but it's not the overflow. What else could it be?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

Every time I take a bath, while I am lying in the bath I notice a foul smell which eminates from around the tap area.

At first I thought it was the overflow drain, so I did the usual full deep cleaning routine and it didn't help. Then I actually completely sealed up the overflow first using a condom and an O-ring and later using mouldable plastic. The seal is air- and water-tight (i.e. I can fill the tub with water past the overflow and no water drains and no air escapes.

I have of course cleaned around the tap itself, including its base and the spout/nozzle including with a biocide. And I figure the smell can't be coming from the pipes which feed the tap, because (obviously) the taps are *off* when I'm lying in the bath!

But the smell is still there. There is no visible dirt, grime, or buildup anywhere nearby.

It's not the water itself. The water smells fine; it's definitely an airborne smell and it only eminates from near the tap.

Any ideas about what this could be? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Sure it's not just your feet? Just kidding, it sounds like sewer gas, probably from a clogged vent or failed trap.

Comment: Does it smell even when you haven't drawn any water for a while?   Do other people smell it as well?   Does it smell if you run only cold water?    Answers to these will help narrow down the source.